# First VBScript not working as expected

Tags: vbscript

Here is one of my first scripts. For some reason, even if `total` is higher than `scored`, it gives an error.

```
Option Explicit
Dim scored, total
scored = InputBox("How many marks did you score?","Percentage calculator:")
If IsNumeric(scored) Then
  total = InputBox("What were the maximum(total) marks?", "Percentage calculator")
Else
  WScript.Echo "Type a number you foolish person!"
End If
If IsNumeric(total) And total > scored Then
  MsgBox "You have scored " & scored*100/total &"% marks", vbOkOnly
ElseIf Not IsNumeric(total) Or total < scored Then
  MsgBox "Error!", 0+16
End If
```

The problem is when I run the program, it asks me for `score`, I input 50 and then I input 100 as `total`. It gives me "error!" as if `total` were smaller than `scored`.

Comment: Could you please [edit] your post and share the error you get?

Comment: I get no error but still, its not working like i wanted it to.

Comment: @Gurman It's b/c he's comparing strings, not integers. The answer to the duplicate question explains that behavior and how to resolve it.